# Infinite Scroll in React JS, but data from Reddit keeps loading and loading

Tags: reactjs, append, infinite-scroll, reddit

please have a look at the code and suggest what should have had done.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './Table.css';
import axios from "axios";

const NEXT_PAGE = "";
function App() {
const [items, setData] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(NEXT_PAGE);
useEffect( () => {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json?after=${page}`)
    .then(res=> res.data)           
    .then(data => {
        setData([...items, ...data.data.children])
        setPage(data.data.after)
    })
}, [page]);

const scrollToEnd = () => {
    setPage(page);
}

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        === document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    ){
        scrollToEnd()
    }
}


return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Displaying data from Reddit API</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {items.length > 0 && items.map((el, i) => 
                    <tr id={el.data.id}>
                        <td>{el.data.id}</td>
                        <td><img src={`${el.data.thumbnail}`} height={`${el.data.thumbnail_height}`} width={`${el.data.thumbnail_width}`} /></td>
                        <td>{el.data.title}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);      
}

export default App;
```

Either it keeps loading data or does not do anything once we reach at the bottom of the page. I only want the next course of data to be loaded when we reach at the bottom of the page. I am trying to learn from various sources but as I am just starting it, I am unable to do it properly. Your valuable suggestion will help me learn things in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

you are actually nevering calling the scrollToEnd() function, because you rarely get the strict equality, it will be either below or above but not strictly equal

give it a try with :

```js
window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        > document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

also in your useEffet function you could use a cleanup function to avoid memory leaks, and also add a catch to deal with errors :

```js
useEffect( () => {
    let mounted = true

    if(mounted)
      axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json?after=${page}`)
      .then(res=> res.data)           
      .then(data => {
          setData([...items, ...data.data.children])
          setPage(data.data.after)
      .catch(err => console.error (err))
      })

    return () => mounted = false;
}, [page]);
```

Also to avoid the infinite refetching of the data, try removing the setPage inside of your async function inside the useEffect hook

```js
const NEXT_PAGE = 0;
function App() {
const [items, setData] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(NEXT_PAGE);

useEffect( () => {
    let mounted = true

    if(mounted)
      axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json?after=${page}`)
      .then(res=> res.data)           
      .then(data => {
          setData([...items, ...data.data.children])
      .catch(err => console.error (err))
      })

    return () => mounted = false;
}, [page]);

const scrollToEnd = () => {
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
}

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        > document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    ){
        scrollToEnd()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do not go to the bottom of page. It automatically keeps loading on page refresh.

Comment: oh yes you are right, you probably have an infinte loop because your useEffect is triggered everytime page changes, and in your use effect you are changin the page with setPage. WHat is the purpose of the setPage inside your async function ?

Comment: It did not work. It does not load anything now.
For the setPage thing, I wanted to assign the next id to variable page, so when we reach at the bottom, it should trigger the function to load next bunch.

Comment: oops sorry i mistyped, you need to write let mounted = true at the top of the useEffect, and not let mounted = false, my bad, i corrected that. It should be working again even though it's not the root fo your problem right now

Comment: i think it is your scrollToEnd function wich should be responsible for modifying the index of the page, by doing something like setPage(prev => prev +1). then your inital NEXT_PAGE variabel would be 0 at the start, and you could remove the setPage fomr inside your useEffect wich is probably what causes the infinite refetching of the data

Comment: Sorry, but i had checked with that too. It still loads continuously once you load page. you are probably right that setPage is causing the issue but there is nothing like numbers for the next one. It is a combination of special characters, numbers, alphabets e.g., t3_v6hjye. In that case, how could we pass that variable if we reach the bottom of the page from scrollToEnd

Comment: i just cheked https://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json?, and it seems there is only one occurence of the 'after' property wich is  t3_v6pq3r. So it seems to me as if you are choosing the wrong attribute to span through pages. it si probably the number of children that should be spaned through

Comment: Exactly. Now the question is how do we fetch and assign that 'after' property when we reach to the bottom of page. I am very much new and that's why do not know how to do it. it took me a while doing this code but no help. Only need your experience.

Comment: you could just fetch the whol Json file at the init, just once, and then you would have all the children at hand , and you can have the front-end display them as you see fit,